Need to create grid of cell dimension 4km^2 and then color them according to the demand within them
I have demand data which is order_id, cust_lat, cust_long in a pandas dataframe.
I just need to create a tiled heatmap so I can decide where all I will need a store. I am comfortable with python and SQL and have access to looker + Bigquery. How to do this quickly?
I also would like it if I could create another layer with the stores and people could have the rights to remove or add stores.

I suggest asking the second part of your question separately (a new question with more details); it's a bit unclear how it relates to the first part. I have written an answer for the first part of your question.

The fastest route I can think of would be to use geopandas.
First you want to convert your latitude and longitude floats to a POINT:
    SELECT
        ST_GEOGPOINT(cust_long, cust_lat) AS location,
        order_id,
      FROM
        some_dataset.orders

Now you can use the Python Client library for BigQuery's Client.query.to_geodataframe method to pull this into a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame.
From here you can plot a heatmap of the data on a map.
Alternative
If the size of the data is very large, this may prove intractable. In that case you'll have to prebin the data and plot the grid another way. Here's one option:
1 - bin up the data
We're going to push the heavy lifting into the BigQuery layer. Let that chunky block of cloud compute do what it does best!
We're going to need

GENERATE_ARRAY
RANGE_BUCKET

The code to get an order count by grid cell will look something like this:
    SELECT
        RANGE_BUCKET(
          cust_lat,
          GENERATE_ARRAY(start_km_lat, end_km_lat, 2)
        ) AS lat_cell,
        RANGE_BUCKET(
          cust_long,
          GENERATE_ARRAY(start_km_lng, end_km_lng, 2)
        ) AS long_cell,
        COUNT(order_id) AS n_orders,
      FROM
        some_dataset.orders
  GROUP BY
        1, 2

This will give you a set of cell positions and order counts.
2 - create a heatmap
Since you're comfortable with Python, a simple option might be to use Seaborn's heatmap function.
This will look something like the following (here I assume you have loaded the data from BigQuery into a Data frame called df):
pivoted_data = df.pivot(index=lat_cell, columns=long_cell, values=n_orders)

sns.heatmap(pivoted_data)


We live on a spherical Earth, and square grid cannot exactly fit the sphere (imagine trying to wrap a ball with paper - it has to fold).
What are the options for drawing heatmap? If the area is relatively small (a few hundred km or less) it might be ok to ignore this problem, and pretend the Earth is flat, it works for local area. If you need a global grid, there are several global grids, most popular ones are S2 and H3, some links here - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/best-practices-for-spatial-clustering-in-bigquery.
For kind-of-flat grid, it is quite easy to generate it using SQL right in BigQuery. A step in degrees for 2km can be computed by computing distance of step of one degree, and dividing 2km by that:
2000. / st_distance(st_geogpoint(lon, lat), st_geogpoint(lon+1, lat)) as dx

And then we can step left and right using GENERATE_ARRAY:
with indices as (
  select * from unnest(generate_array(-10, 9, 1)) i
), 
center as (
  select -122.3 lon, 47.6 lat
),
consts as (
  select 
    2000. / st_distance(st_geogpoint(lon, lat), 
                st_geogpoint(lon+1, lat)) as dx,
    2000. / st_distance(st_geogpoint(lon, lat), 
                st_geogpoint(lon, lat+1)) as dy 
  from center
)
select 
  rand() color,
  st_makepolygon(st_makeline([
    st_geogpoint(lon + dx*x.i, lat + dy*y.i),
    st_geogpoint(lon + dx*(x.i+1), lat + dy*y.i),
    st_geogpoint(lon + dx*(x.i+1), lat + dy*(y.i+1)),
    st_geogpoint(lon + dx*x.i, lat + dy*(y.i+1))
  ])) poly
from indices x, indices y, center, consts


